# in keycloak how to change the password of an authenticated user

Tags: keycloak, change-password

In the keycloak administration, if I set the "Required User Action" of a user to "Update Password". The user is asked for a new password after a successful login, calling:

https://SERVER/auth/realms/REALM/login-actions/required-action?execution=UPDATE_PASSWORD&client_id=CLIENT_ID&tab_id=TAB_ID

Calling this URL with a user logged-in but not configured "Update Password" I get a message "User is already logged in".

What would be the correct URL to call from an external application, e.g. from a menu with actions edit-profile, change-password...

**Edit**: In our application we authenticate users managed in keycloak. We would like to be able to link a keycloak page (similar as the one posted) where the user can update/change his password (e.g. old-pw, new-pw, confirm-pw).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on Keycloak 12 (latest version at the time of writing the answer)

You can ask users to change their profile details or passwords from the manage account section. You can get the URL of that screen and direct users to that.

["manage account" link location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04DP9.png)

[Account management screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz59l.png)

Comment: Thanks, currently I run into this issue though: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/forbidden-error-when-accessing-user-management/8041
Maybe this is resolved in the next release.